# React Ant Design Steps -- NO 'Check Icon'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I use `AntD` library and want to make use of the **Steps** Component. There I have the **vertical** alignment which all works great. However I would like to remove the **checkmark icon** and just show the numbers. I want to use it as kind of step by step guide and don't need the checkmark icons. I would prefer the active icon to be as it is now and the others that are not `active` as the steps that are currently not **Finished**.
Does anyone know how to do this?

I have a sketch and [some code](https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-steps-with-form-checking-gusp4).

[image]

I would be thankful for help here!

Searching the official documentation and here already, but couldn't find the answer.

---

The solution I came up with based on the help of **Dennis Vash** is the following. I just post it here for others if they need it too.

[image: Edit Q-57708920-CustomSteps]

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and NEVER  a third party site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to control the [`Step`'s property `status`](https://ant.design/components/steps/#Steps.Step), for example:

```
<Step
  title="Finished"
  description="This is a description."
  status={current === 0 ? "current" : current > 0 ? "wait" : "process"}
/>
```

Notice in the next example, that step *"Finished"* remains `wait` after moving to next step, where other steps will change to `finish` status.

You can control the status with the next values:

> `current` `wait` `process` `finish` `error`

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  state = { current: 0 };
  render() {
    const { current } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Steps direction="vertical" current={current}>
          <Step
            title="Finished"
            description="This is a description."
            status={
              current === 0 ? 'current' : current > 0 ? 'wait' : 'process'
            }
          />
          <Step title="In Progress" description="This is a description." />
          <Step title="Waiting" description="This is a description." />
        </Steps>
        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ current: current - 1 })}>
          Prev
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ current: current + 1 })}>
          Next
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

[image: Edit Q-57708920-CustomSteps]

Moreover, you always can make custom steps with `icon` property which accepts `ReactNode`, for example, current steps are just circle `Button`s that changing their type/icon, refer to [`Button` API](https://ant.design/components/button/) for more info.

Comment: I tried your code and it works great for the first item however i tried to reprodcue it for the others and i cam up with this solution which is the most near to what I want to achieve. So thank you for your answer! https://codesandbox.io/embed/q-57708920-customsteps-621e0?fontsize=14

Answer (score 2):

I have one workaround.....

You can use `icon` prop for display step numbers. like this...

```
<Steps direction="vertical" current={1}>
  <Step title="Finished" icon={1} description="This is a description." />
  <Step title="In Progress" icon={2} description="This is a description." />
  <Step title="Waiting" icon={3} description="This is a description." />
</Steps>
```

code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-steps-with-form-checking-8fi3t

Comment: Its a creat idea too and I will try to replace the icons with buttons again. However, I found also another good answer and posted it already.